# How to authorize to mercure subscriptions API?

Tags: authorization, mercure

Anytime I access the mercure subscriptions API, I receive a "401 Unauthorized" response.

Publishing and Subscribing to topics works alright - but the subscription API doesn't seem to like my JWT credentials. I don't seem to understand the payload of JWT needed for access.

I tried:

**Enable / Disable subscriptions API**

I'm running my own mercure docker image with subscriptions enabled:
MERCURE_EXTRA_DIRECTIVES: subscriptions

Without that directive, GET requests to `/.well-known/mercure/subscriptions` return a 404 not found.
With the directive I receive 401 Unauthorized responses:
So I believe it's a permission problem.

**Use JWT with subscribe payload signed with MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY**

```
{
  "mercure": {
    "subscribe": [
      "//prototype/messages/{channel}"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Use JWT with publish payload signed with MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY**

```
{
  "mercure": {
    "publish": [
      "//prototype/messages/{channel}"
    ]
  }
}
```

Both Token work for subscribing - respectively publishing to given topics.

Unfortunately, both don't work for accessing the subscription API via GET request:

`https://mercure.domain.tld/.well-known/mercure/subscriptions/%2F%2Fprototype%2Fmessages%2F%7Bchannel%7D?authorization=[JWT]`

I always receive an 401 Unauthorized response.